# Staging Database - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, staging

I am working on a database design for an application. The database has been designed, to be specific, Tables, views, Stored procedures etc are in place.
There are total 7 tables, 8-10 views and 4-5 procedures and some of the Triggers may follow. Out of 7 tables, there are 3 transactional tables, for which data will keep growing.

Now based on a specific implementation of the application, the data may grow exponentially. Because of which the performance would surely suffer. Because of reporting requirements, if I continue to use this single database, even reports are prone to crash.

What would be best approaches to have performance and archival/Stagging together? Performance in terms of reporting and application.

I was thinking to write a few scripts which would transfer the data (how it is currently placed in the tables.. {the structure etc}) from current database to a new, but perhaps in such a way that all data is transformed to either a single table or a few tables than original database, such that even if I purge those data(for a designated period) from original database, but still it is available in new database considering that in future there could be a new reporting requirement which a customer may ask on existing data.

Could you all please shed some more light of knowledge onto this?

Comment: You could use Database snapshot and report out of that

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx -- I'd look at transactional replication.  Replicate to your second server and design an ETL process (ssis or procs) to push aggregate data into a data warehouse off the replicated dB.  You can index a replicated dB to support reports/ETLs without impacting production.  Somewhat beyond the scope of anything you'll get an answer to here, but its a start.

Comment: You make many assumptions. There may not be as much data as you expect (100 rows? 1000 rows? 1 million rows?) with sufficient index reporting might be just fine.

Comment: +1 @Nick.McDermaid. Apart from making assumptions instead of using data, you also need to provide details on access patterns. For instance, an OLTP system that need to support reporting that has lots of singleton insert/updates will have very different performance characteristics compared to one that has lots of batch updates/inserts. Also, what do the queries look like and what do they do? Storage IO frequently comes up as one of the top performance bottlenecks but it's not the only one and it's not 100% of the time. Need more details.